# Java VPN в приложении

Tags: java, android

Добрый день. Есть впн сервер. Через настройки в андроиде я к нему подключаюсь, весь трафик идет через него. Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно сделать впн соединение только для своего приложения?

Comment: А у вас приложение общается с одним узлом?

Comment: да, с одним узлом

Comment: Тогда зачем там VPN?